# if/else jquery between three elements

Tags: jquery, if-statement, switch-statement

alright, i am trying to make it so when you click one div it "turns off" the other two div buttons as well as making some content invisible

jquery:

```
    var open1 = false;
    var open2 = false;
    var open3 = false;

    $(document).ready(function(){



$("#gun").on('click',
   function(){
        open2 = !open2;

        if(open2) {
          $("img.dataselectgun").fadeTo(0, 1.0);
          $("img.dataselectpop").fadeTo(0, 0.0);
          $("img.dataselectart").fadeTo(0, 0.0);
          $("#popactivated").attr("id","pop");
          $("#artactivated").attr("id","art");
          $(this).attr("id","gunactivated");
        }
        else {
            $("img.dataselectpop").fadeTo(0, 1);
            $("img.dataselectart").fadeTo(0, 1);
            $("#gunactivated").attr("id","gun");
        }

   }
);

$("#pop").on('click',
   function(){
        open1 = !open1;

        if(open1) {
          $("img.dataselectgun").fadeTo(0, 0.0);
          $("img.dataselectpop").fadeTo(0, 1.0);
          $("img.dataselectart").fadeTo(0, 0.0);
          $("#gunactivated").attr("id","gun");
          $("#artactivated").attr("id","art");
          $(this).attr("id","popactivated");

        }
        else {
            $("img.dataselectgun").fadeTo(0, 1);
            $("img.dataselectart").fadeTo(0, 1);
            $("#popactivated").attr("id","pop");
        }

   }
);

$("#art").on('click',
   function(){
        open3 = !open3;

        if(open3) {
          $("img.dataselectgun").fadeTo(0, 0.0);
          $("img.dataselectpop").fadeTo(0, 0.0);
          $("img.dataselectart").fadeTo(0, 1.0);
          $("#popactivated").attr("id","pop");
          $("#gunactivated").attr("id","gun");
          $(this).attr("id","artactivated");
        }
        else {
            $("img.dataselectgun").fadeTo(0, 1);
            $("img.dataselectpop").fadeTo(0, 1);
            $("#popactivated").attr("id","art");
        }

   }
);

    });
```

alright ha ha that's a lot of jquery, so here is the html:

```
    <div id="header">
    <div class="home" id="home" ><a href="index.html"><p><img class="rollover" src="images/home-crown.png" width="100px" /></p></a></div>
    <div class="topnav" id="gun"><p>GUN</p></div>
    <div class="topnav" id="pop"><p>POP</p></div>
    <div class="topnav" id="art"><p>ART</p></div>
</div>
    <div id="bodyparts">
    <div class="pillow" ></div>
    <div class="content" id="artbox"><p><img class="dataselectart" src="images/art9.png" width="300px" /></p></div>
    <div class="content" id="popbox"><p><img class="dataselectpop" src="images/pop9.png" width="300px" /></p></div>
    <div class="content" id="gunbox"><p><img class="dataselectgun" src="images/gun9.png" width="300px" /></p></div>
</div>
```

alright sorry about the large code but here is the main problem, each individual "button" works but when two "button"'s are clicked (or true) they create some conflict; i tried toggle but received the same issue, if this were to be done with switching that would be great, but i am new to jquery and have no idea how; any help would be great

thanks, in advance (i know my code is long a messy; sorry)

edit: changed some things on suggestion; works better but is there a way to affect another if/else with a if /else (effectively altering jquery with jquery?)

Comment: I'd suggest you read about the [DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).  You can factor out those three blocks of code into a single function that you pass a few arguments to.  Also, there's no need for separate `open` and `shut` variables as they are always just opposite one another.

Comment: You can't use one variable to track the state of three elements. You need a separate variable for each element you have. Also, there's no need to have `open` and `shut` separately--you can just use `open` and  test for `!open` where you now have `shut`.

Comment: Events are bound to elements not their IDs.

Comment: What is the reason for changing the id values on your elements?

Comment: @Juhana so i would have to use 3 different open variables? (the shut was there because i was being an idiot ha ha i will take that out)

Comment: @jfriend00 it activates some css that shows the viewer what has been activated (sorry about the repeated things, i just have not got around to developing a shortened trick for it)

Comment: I suggest that for now you use 3 different variables and when you get it working take it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com. There's quite a lot of things that could be improved.

Comment: @Juhana much agreed, I am really new to jquery (literally taught myself 2 days ago) so i know it needs cleaning; i will try the variables and hope something works...

Comment: You need to change classes, not IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the one that was clicked shown then you don't need to worry about keeping track of state. This can be done with the following:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DBFvZ/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.topnav').on('click', function () {

        // Get the <img> tag for the link that was clicked
        var myImg = $('.dataselect' + this.id);

        // Fade the <img> tag
        myImg.fadeTo(0, 1.0);

        // Get the other <img> tags, exclude myImg and fade them
        $('.content img').not(myImg).fadeTo(0, 0.0);

    });
});
```

Comment: there is some other html that i did not include, it is used to retrieve the images for these 3; i need those images to stay there so when the user deactivates the button those images show, great idea though,

Comment: The images aren't showing up because they're on your server, when you use this JS in your site the images will still be there. I didn't change the HTML.

Comment: oh sorry i meant there is more html that i did not put in the post;

Comment: It is not really clear exactly what you want the various controls to do together.  You've got your `topnav` `DIV`s that are clickable, you've got corresponding images, and you've got ?buttons?, perhaps the IDs `#popactivated` `#gunactivated` `#artactivated` from your js.  What should happen on a click?

Comment: @DavidTansey in addition to the buttons above; i have other buttons made with html that change the images in the content boxes to different years (those are the buttons in charge of changing the image);  the activated classes are buttons that have been selected (switched on) gun,pop, and art are the unactive classes,(not on).

Comment: They go inside topnav div because the entire page resizes and such. When someone clicks the gun div, it should "stay active" (turn to gunactive) until clicked again, while deactivated all other "buttons" also while "soloing" its corresponding image content (dataselectgun)